# high irq on ubuntu 18.10 for nvidia gtx 1060

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, nvidia-graphics-card, nvidia-settings

I just bought a new laptop containing nvidia gtx 1060, i7 8th gen. installed ubuntu 18.10 (kernel 4.18.0-15)

I have been facing consistent high irq on it.

I tried various nvidia drivers on it (415 latest -> naouveau -> 396 current ). However, I aint able to fix it. how should I go about it. please help. I am unable to use laptop effectively.

I have currently selected 'intel' graphics card to save on battery.

[top command snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2R3S.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nvidia, nouveau drivers seem to be buggy.
I was trying to use laptop with integrated graphics since I didnt (ironically) have need for a dedicated gpu. hence, I disabled dGFX in BIOS. removed nvidia, nouveau drivers.

suspend/resume was still giving me an issue. a gentleman adviced me to remove i2c_hid module before suspend and load it after resume. and voila, laptop was back in the game. with double battery performance to boot, since dGFX was not given any power.